# Sustraer una palabra desde una cadena de texto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código sencillo, con el que planteo realizar una operación y al funcionar colocárselo a un cogido mas grande necesito colocar en un input lo que este antes de **Precio:** y Despues de **" - "** en tiempo real.

Por ejemplo en una cadena de texto que contiene **"REFRESCO 2L HIT-NARANJA - COCACOLA Precio: 1500.00"**

Yo deseo que la palabra **COCACOLA**, ya que es la marca del producto, se guarde en una variable para imprimirla en un input, pero se trata de guardar lo que esta después de **" - "** y antes de **"Precio:"**

Por ejemplo con el siguiente código logro obtener lo que esta antes de **Precio:**

```
const PrincAct = /\w+(?= Precio)/;
const palabra = m1.match(PrincAct)
document.getElementById(prinact).value = palabra;
```

El Problema radica, en puede existir en una cadena de texto lo siguiente **"REFRESCO 2L NARANJA-ORANGE Precio: 1000.00"** Se me guardar en mi input la palabra **ORANGE**  y no quiero que esto suceda, pues **ORANGE** no es una marca registrada

Como dato adicional en mi cadena de texto existen 2 signos iguales **"-"** la diferencia es que uno esta separado por espacios. y este que esta separado por espacio es mi referencia a tomar para capturar la palabra que esta antes de **Precio**

Otro dato es que este código multiplica y totaliza el valor de precio.

Quiero lograrlo utilizando solo JavaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es_ES">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var nextinput = 0;
        function AgregarCampos() {
            nextinput++;
            campo = '<li id="idLi' + nextinput + '">' +
        
           '<select id="txt' + nextinput + '" step="any" oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\',\'prinact' + nextinput + '\');" >' +
             '<option value="REFRESCO 2L HIT-NARANJA - COCACOLA Precio: 1500.00">REFRESCO 2L HIT-NARANJA - COCACOLA Precio: 1500.00</option>   ' +
             '<option value="REFRESCO 2L GOLDEN-NARANJA - PEPSICOLA Precio: 1200.00">REFRESCO 2L GOLDEN-NARANJA - PEPSICOLA Precio: 1200.00</option>   ' +
             '<option value="REFRESCO 2L NARANJA-ORANGE Precio: 1000.00">REFRESCO 2L NARANJA-ORANGE Precio: 1000.00"</option>   ' +
             '</select>' +
            '<input type="text" size="15" id="prinact' + nextinput + '" step="any"  oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\',\'prinact' + nextinput + '\');" />' +
            '<input type="number" size="15" id="nmb' + nextinput + '" step="any"    oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\',\'prinact' + nextinput + '\');" />' +
            '<input type="text" size="15"   id="acumu' + nextinput + '" step="any" class="monto"/></li>';

            $("#campos").append(campo);
        }
        function multiplicar(txt, nmb, acumu, prinact) {
            var m1 = document.getElementById(txt).value;
            var m2 = document.getElementById(nmb).value;

            const PrincAct = /\w+(?= Precio)/;
            const palabra = m1.match(PrincAct)
            document.getElementById(prinact).value = palabra;

            var P = /precio: (\d+)/i;
            var matchA = m1.match(P);
            var Price = parseInt(matchA[1]);
            r = Price * m2;
            document.getElementById(acumu).value = r;

            var total = 0;
            $(".monto").each(function () {
                if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                    total += 0;
                } else {
                    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                }
            });
            document.getElementById('T').value = total;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post">
         <div align="left">
    <a href="#" onclick="AgregarCampos();">Agregar Producto</a>
    <ul id="campos"></ul>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    Total
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="T" value="0" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco los comentarios que puedan Darme para lograr lo que necesito?

Comment: Y para la tercera opción _NARANJA-ORANGE_ ¿Qué marca debería aparecer?

Comment: Debería quedar vació pues no consiguió coincidencia

Comment: Entonces puedes usar esto `/(?<= - )\w+(?= Precio)/`, ya que la cadena a buscar debe de ir precedida por  ' - ', para saber más puedes buscar **Aserción de búsqueda inversa**

Comment: @OscarG gracias por responder, pero eso que indicas no funciona, y estoy leyendo Aserción de búsqueda inversa para lograrlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta la estructura de tu string, podemos usar una expresión regular para obtener el precio

```
[0-9]{1,}(\.[0-9]{1,}?)$
```

Poniendo un punto y más números después como contenido opcional, ya que con solo `[0-9]{1,}$` no hará match a `100.00`

Luego de eso, vamos a separar el string con [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para separar el string

```
str.split(string " ") : array
```

Evidentemente, si el primer elemento del array que nos da es igual al string completo, no hay marca

```js
function processStr(s) {
    const sp = s.split(" - ");
    const p = s.match(/[0-9]{1,}(\.[0-9]{1,}?)$/)[0] - 0;
    // - 0 para convertirlo a número
    // Un string con un entero no se pueden restar y el resultado es un entero
    return sp[0] === s ? ["", p] : [sp[1].trim().split(" ")[0], p];
    // Operador ternario, equivalente a lo de abajo
    /*if (sp[0] === s) {
      return ["", p];
      // No hay marca
    } else {
      return [sp[1].trim().split(" ")[0], p];
    }*/
}

var nextinput = 0;

function AgregarCampos() {
    nextinput++;
    campo = '<li id="idLi' + nextinput + '">' +

        '<select id="txt' + nextinput + '" step="any" oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\',\'prinact' + nextinput + '\');" >' +
        '<option value="REFRESCO 2L HIT-NARANJA - COCACOLA Precio: 1500.00">REFRESCO 2L HIT-NARANJA - COCACOLA Precio: 1500.00</option>   ' +
        '<option value="REFRESCO 2L GOLDEN-NARANJA - PEPSICOLA Precio: 1200.00">REFRESCO 2L GOLDEN-NARANJA - PEPSICOLA Precio: 1200.00</option>   ' +
        '<option value="REFRESCO 2L NARANJA-ORANGE Precio: 1000.00">REFRESCO 2L NARANJA-ORANGE Precio: 1000.00"</option>   ' +
        '</select>' +
        '<input type="text" size="15" id="prinact' + nextinput + '" step="any"  oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\',\'prinact' + nextinput + '\');" />' +
        '<input type="number" size="15" id="nmb' + nextinput + '" step="any"    oninput="multiplicar(\'txt' + nextinput + '\',\'nmb' + nextinput + '\',\'acumu' + nextinput + '\',\'prinact' + nextinput + '\');" />' +
        '<input type="text" size="15"   id="acumu' + nextinput + '" step="any" class="monto"/></li>';

    $("#campos").append(campo);
}

function multiplicar(txt, nmb, acumu, prinact) {
    var m1 = document.getElementById(txt).value;
    var m2 = document.getElementById(nmb).value;

    const [palabra, r] = processStr(m1);
    document.getElementById(prinact).value = palabra;
    document.getElementById(acumu).value = r * m2;

    var total = 0;
    $(".monto").each(function() {
        if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
            total += 0;
        } else {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('T').value = total;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es_ES">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" method="post">
         <div align="left">
    <a href="#" onclick="AgregarCampos();">Agregar Producto</a>
    <ul id="campos"></ul>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    Total
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="T" value="0" disabled>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Si no es igual al string completo, obtenemos el segundo elemento del array el cual contendrá una plantilla así

```
(Marca) Precio: ....
```

Entonces, usamos [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) para quitar espacios innecesarios al inicio y al final del segundo elemento del array, luego usamos [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) otra vez para separar el elemento por cada espacio, tendremos algo así

```
[
    "(Marca)",
    "Precio:",
    "....",
]
```

Y evidentemente el primer elemento del nuevo array será la marca

Comment: disculpa el tiempo en responder, tengo una duda en esta linea me marca error const [palabra, r] = processStr(m1); el error me lo da en los corchetes se coloca en rojo, Otra consulta debería funcionar aunque en vez de un select solo sea un input? ya que lo probe asi y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Para que me dejara de marcar error en esta linea

```
const [palabra, r] = processStr(m1);
```

Solo quite los corchetes y la variable r quedando así:

```
const palabra = processStr(m1);
```

De esta manera tuve que agregar nuevamente mis variables para multiplicar

```
var P = /precio: (\d+)/i;
var matchA = m1.match(P);
var Price = parseInt(matchA[1]);
r = Price * m2;
document.getElementById(acumu).value = r;
```

En la funtion **processStr(s)** tuve que acomodar la linea que colocaste donde retorna pues si no lo hacia donde quiero que quede grabada **COCACOLA**, se visualizara también el precio estando así **COCACOLA,1500.00**

A esta Linea, le quite la variable p, para que no me trajera el valor numérico de precio

```
return sp[0] === s ? ["", p] : [sp[1].trim().split(" ")[0], p];
```

Quedando asi:

```
 return sp[0] === s ? [""] : [sp[1].trim().split(" ")[0]];
```

De esta manera ya no me marca error y hace lo que necesito.

Muchas Gracias **anythingg**